# Why is this JPanel still being repainted?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a custom `JLayeredPane` and two custom child `JPanel`'s. I repaint everything in a `while` loop in a `Thread`. I have used `RepaintManager.currentManager(backPanel).markCompletelyClean(backPanel);` to stop the repainting the `backPanel` `JPanel`. As to not waste system resources. However, This does not work. As we can see in the `paintComponent` method, if you run and compile the code below, you will see that the statement "Reccursion" is reccursively repeated in the output, from the `System.out.println("Reccursion")` method call in the  `paintComponent` method.

Why is the `backPanel` `JPanel` still being repainted and why is the method `System.out.println("Reccursion")` still being called, When I have used `RepaintManager.currentManager(backPanel).markCompletelyClean(backPanel);`.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JLayeredPane {
    static JFrame frame;
    static Main main;
    static Dimension screenSize;
    public Main() {     
        JPanel backPanel = new BackPanel();
        JPanel frontPanel = new FrontPanel();
        add(backPanel, new Integer(7));
        add(frontPanel, new Integer(8));

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true){
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();

        RepaintManager.currentManager(backPanel).markCompletelyClean(backPanel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        frame = new JFrame("Game"); // Just use the constructor

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        main = new Main();
        frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);



    }
    public class BackPanel extends JPanel{
        public boolean drawn = false;
        public BackPanel(){
            setVisible(true);
            setOpaque(false);
            setSize(screenSize);
            JLabel test1 = new JLabel("Test1");
            JLabel test2 = new JLabel("Test2");
            add(test1);
            add(test2);
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, screenSize.width, 200);
            System.out.print("Reccursion");
        }
    }
    public class FrontPanel extends JPanel{

        public FrontPanel(){
            setVisible(true);
            setOpaque(false);
            setSize(screenSize);
            JLabel test = new JLabel("Test");
            add(test);
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0+screenSize.width/2, 0, screenSize.width/4, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is outdated, don't touch the RepaintManager and Thread paused, use SwingTimer , for more info to search here, before to read Oracle tutorial about Java2D, and Custom Painting too

Comment: I don;t know how RepaintManager.currentManager(backPanel).markCompletelyClean(backPanel); works. It's a lot of fluff. If you start a thread that repaints endlesly that's what will happen. You have to create some mechanism to stop that. For example if you want to stop repainting after two times you put a counter there. So state your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The method "paintComponent" is called quite often and without your "permission" (it's been giving me a hard time too...)
You can't do anything about it, just don't generate new data everytime in this method or the appearance may change as often.
Good luck

https://books.google.fr/books?id=KXz6AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=paintcomponent+called+repeatedly&source=bl&ots=AEql59yy51&sig=Ezny1GptXRthd1e0tuQFdM5peoo&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjun4j6rJHOAhWK2xoKHYaPCEQ4ChDoAQgkMAE#v=onepage&q=paintcomponent%20called%20repeatedly&f=false